# Stop Opera Mobile from outlining touched elements

Tags: javascript, html, css, opera-mobile

Does anybody know how to stop Opera Mobile (Windows emulator) from displaying bluish outlines for touched HTML elements?

Blue outline appears when touched:
[image: blue outline]

I want this:
[image: this is what I want]

Comment: That is apparently a feature of Opera Mobile. Perhaps contacting their devs may help because as far as they are concerned that is a feature to improve usage and accessability for users. There most likely isn't an easy work around.

Comment: Check out the spatial navigation section in this link -- http://dev.opera.com/articles/view/characteristics-of-widgets-on-mobile-pho/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably not the answer you want to hear, but at present it is not possible to disable or override the blue highlight. As Tony318 says, this is by design to enable users to see immediately which link they've pressed (especially important with small buttons/links close together). Being able to override the outline has been logged as a feature request, however, so this behaviour may change in the future.

Incidentally, here's a good general resource for disabling outlines, although it doesn't apply to Opera Mobile in this case: http://people.opera.com/patrickl/experiments/keyboard/test